# The Web Hosting Connundrum for "not quite" developers

Tags: hosting, drupal

Apologies if this post feels like its been covered elsewhere, but I don't think it has.

I've been down a winding web hosting road. To date, I've tried:  Joyent, Media Temple, Bluehost, Hostgator, and finally Linode. The reason for switching are likely obvious to everyone: speed. With the exception of the lightening fast Linode, all of the shared hosts are absolutely sloooow.

**What do do when you're not really a "developer"**

While I'v grown addicted to the speed of Linode, I really don't feel like its where I should be. I have this nagging feeling in the back of my mind that one of these days (likely soon), I'm going to run into something that i won't be able to figure out and i'll have days worth of downtime.  Just the other day, for example, I realized that one of my domains wasn't sending emails. After 4(!) hours looking into the problem, I still can't get sendmail or postfix to work.   Four hours!!

**I want to be a Drupal expert, not a Ubuntu expert**

That's really the heart of my problem:  I spend way too much time learning Ubuntu's ins-and-outs, and not nearly enough time working on Drupal.

So here goes:   Is there a web host out there anywhere that offers the speed of Linode, but will let me focus on Drupal instead of sys-admin-ing?

Thanks!

[ I know, I know.  There are going to be lots of people who read this saying - "just learn Ubuntu like a real developer". And I get that. I do.  But when I work full-time and try and develop some of these sites in my evenings and weekends, I'm really feeling like the sys-admin stuff gets in the way.

Comment: Right. I guess the obvious PS at the end here is:  If there isn't a company offering good speeds without the VPS overhead for semi-developers like me....then I think there's a good business opportunity there.

Comment: I'm confused... do you not want to be a developer, or you don't want to be a SysAdmin? Or both? I take it you just want to be a content editor?

Answer (score 2):

You want a managed server, not a VPS or dedicated server.  They're more expensive because someone administrates them for you.  But, they're out there.  A quick google for "managed server" will find some.

A lot of the same companies that provide shared or dedicated hosting will also do managed systems, just ask!

Comment: Rackspace is a well known example of this space, though they're way more expensive than you want for a development box.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like BlackMesh would be a great fit for your needs.  We've been around for seven years now, and we've been a big supporter (and user) of Drupal since v4.  Give me a ring at 888-473-0854 (press 1 for sales, or dial my direct extension, 713).  There are few things worse for productivity than spending your precious development time trying to get sysadmin-y things like mail working properly.